# I will call somebody else, not neither him nor you

Tags: negation, double-negation, neither-nor

I have a sentence

***I will call neither you nor him***

I guess it means

***I won't call neither you nor him***

Out of it it's not clear whether I will call anyone at all but I want to say that I will call but among the people I will call there will be neither you nor him. Can I say it like

***I will call somebody else, NOT neither you nor him***

or should it be like

***I will call somebody else, neither you nor him***

I am worried **NOT neither you nor him** = 2 negations which is a bad grammar.

Comment: _I won't call neither you nor him_ is also a double negative; you would use _either, or_ in this case.

Comment: What about "I will call, but neither you nor him"?

Comment: I suppose that works in theory, but I can't imagine anyone wording it like that in real life.

Comment: How would you rephrase it? Why is it bad?

Comment: It's not 'bad', just unnatural. "I'm going to call somebody, but it won't be you and it won't be him!"

Comment: Isn't it a little wordy...?

Comment: People don't always express themselves in the most succinct manner in everyday conversation.

Answer (score 1):

> I will call somebody else, neither you nor him

is better; as you said, it avoids a double negative. Though it's worth noting, this isn't actually against the rules of grammar, it's just a style rule. (See [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/3-things-you-must-know-about-double-negatives/))

Personally, I'd put the "somebody else" after the negation to give it more emphasis:

> I will call neither you nor him--somebody else.

> I will call neither you nor him. I'll call somebody else.

> I will call neither you nor him, but somebody else.

It's totally up to you though. Use whatever sounds better.

Comment: And while a double negative isn't wrong, using it means that the second sentence in the question does *not* mean the same thing as the first—it means the opposite. So, despite the discussion about style, the premise of the question itself is wrong.

Comment: I wanted to say that people said/wrote I will call neither you nor him but in their heads they mean I won't call neither you nor him. Like, people don't normally say so but they mean it. No?

Comment: _I will call neither...nor_ = _I won't call either...or_